# How to drop values in nested struct if data type is null

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I have data structure like below shown. What I want is to drop certain values within field3(struct) if the data type is null, and also drop field3.ZZZ completely if ZZZ data type is null.

```
 root
 |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- XXX: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- s: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- v: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- YYY: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- s: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- v: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ZZZ: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: null (containsNull = true)
```

I did lots of research, but haven't found a clear way to solve this requirement. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: what do you mean by "if xxx data type is null" ? do you mean the whole column is null or some rows ? and should we delete the column or only the null rows ?